# Dynamically spread a CSS effect across a flexible amount of div's

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a menu where every `li` has a green background color. I (the client) want each next `li` a bit lighter.

Currently I have it like this:

```
.Menu > li:nth-child(2):before {
    background-color: rgba(84,175,50,0.93) !important;
}

.Menu > li:nth-child(3):before {
    background-color: rgba(84,175,50,0.86);
}

.Menu > li:nth-child(4):before {
    background-color: rgba(84,175,50,0.79);
}
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<ul class="hoofdMenu vertical nested">
  <li><a href="#">Zuid-Holland</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Scholen</a></li>
  <li id="klikken">
    <a href="#">Parken</a>
    <ul class="menu vertical nested">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Tuinen</a></li>

  <li class="meerWitruimte"><a href="grafische-vormgeving.html">Grafisch Vormgeving</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>    
</ul>
```

but I want the steps to spread across all `li`'s directly inside .menu (not a level deeper) and spread dynamically. Instead of hard-coded like I did myself, it should be dynamically/automatically in case the size of the menu would change.

**Note:**
I want each `li` to have a solid color. Not a gradient inside/behind.

**Current sample**
[image]

---

*My thoughts went to using jQuery and using `.count()` to count all `li`'s and then apply the effect, but I wasn't successful. Most likely due to not skilled enough.*

Comment: It seems you have an unwanted `d` letter in front of the last menu  child selector, or am I wrong?

Comment: My menu is actually written in Dutch, would actually would have been 'hoofdMenu' which translates to 'main menu'. I forgot one D. I did this for English interpretation purposes :) Thanks for the headsup

Comment: The Dutch is not a problem, but please add the HTML to the question.

Comment: Have you thought about using a CSS preprocessor, such as Sass, to create the styles? You could use a for loop (see: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10) to create the CSS. Sass also has color functions you could use to iterate through a gradation. jQuery doesn't sound like a good idea since it would add unnecessary overhead on the user side.

Comment: @Darren I think that wouldn't be a problem if that fulfills the question. I agree SASS would be a better choice than jQuery (which already is in use) but didn't think of that. Go ahead, thanks!

Comment: css is not dynamic. Even when using a preprocessor (LESS/SASS etc.) you wouldn't be able to know the length of the menu upon page load. It's still css that is deployed, compiled, to the web site.

Comment: @JNF Correct, which is why I originally added it as a comment rather than an answer. If the menu will be fairly fixed in number, preprocessed CSS would be much more performant.

Comment: @Darren but if the menu was a fixed number then my original solution (a CSS line for each item) fits. Most likely the number remains fixed, but in case it will ever change the colors adapt. And that was the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this, is to use a bit of JavaScript to calculate the colors. That also makes it easier to handle a flexible number of items. You could do it using jQuery, but I think vanilla JavaScript is just as easy.

I've documented the code with comments and tried to address your additional requests from the comments. The code is a bit verbose. I've done the calculation and generation of the color value in a couple of steps to show clearly what is done. You could bring that down to a more brief calculation, although I think it can't hurt to be a little verbose. Declaring an extra variable and having an extra line of code won't kill the performance of your page.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu > li');
var count = items.length;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  // First, which step is this (between 0 and 1). This helps changing 
  // the formula to other kinds of values or gradients if you need to.
  var step = i / (count - 1);

  // Alpha value. 1 - X to reverse the value from 1 downto 0. 
  // X = step * 0.5, because you want from 100% to 50% instead of all the 
  // way down to 0%. If you would want from 100% to 75%, change this 
  // number to 0.25.
  var alpha = 1 - step * 0.5;

  // Build an rgba color value.
  var color = 'rgba(84,175,50,' + alpha + ')';
  console.log(color);

  // And set it.
  items[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
.menu > li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Dinges</li>
  <li>Danges</li>
  <li>Denges</li>
  <li>Dunges</li>
  <li>Donges</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first line, shouldn't it be `.menu > li` if selecting only first level `li` inside `.menu` ? :)

Comment: If you want just the first level, then yes. I was already typing away before you posted your HTML.

Comment: Oh and a quick update: Is it possible to degrade it from 255 to 120 (or 100% to 50%) instead of 100%/255 to 0?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it. It now used RGBA, and it is in the range of 1 to 0.5 alpha transparency.

Comment: Perfect! If you'd like to see the result (on a longer menu): http://imgur.com/vOuFjV9

Comment: @KostasX Thanks. I decided to make the code a little more verbose, for demonstration purposes. Of couse you can make it a bit shorter, and you would typically do this in a function instead of declaring a bunch of (global) variables. Your version is nice, but note it doesn't work in IE8 (if that would be important).

Answer (score 1):

This is my take using JQuery.

[**See Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/q41en9bm/3/) -> Updated based on comments

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var itemNum = $('li').size(); // count number of elements

  $('li').each(function(index, value) {

    // adjust the gradient: itemnumber / total items / 2
    // since we want to only do the gradient from 100% to 50% we divide by 2
    var gradient = 1 - ((index + 1) / itemNum) / 2;

    $(value).css('background-color', 'rgba(84, 175, 50,' + gradient + ')');
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class='menu'>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you use 'gradient' as keyword, you may use one, so it shapes li as well ;) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gPLXoJ (your js inside)

Comment: Opacity is 0.9 downto 0.3, and it's fixed to the number of items. If you have more than 8, the last ones will all be white.

Comment: @GCyrillus fair comments... just went for a quick demo instead of a full solution... will update answer with suggestions - thanks

Comment: @GolezTrol , well it basicly works, next improvement would be, indeed,  to count lis before downing opacity color ;)

Comment: @GolezTrol correct, the OP also wanted gradient down to 50% (instead of all down to white) will update answer - thanks for comments

Comment: That's a lot better. It now generates the gradient down to 50%, regardless of the number of items. But it doesn't start at 100%, but at (I think) `100% - (50% / items.count)`.

Answer (score 1):

While CSS won't dynamically adjust to the number of menu items, so it may not fit your needs, it would be more performant than JavaScript the browser has to run on every page load. You can always generate more styles than you need to ensure additional menu items will get a background.

For reference, here's SCSS that will create the necessary styles:

```
$menuCount: 6;
$menuColor: #339933;

@for $i from 1 through $menuCount {
  li:nth-child( #{$i} ) {
    background-color: lighten( $menuColor, ( $i * 5 ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Packing the code of @goleztrol a little bit, and reducing LOCs.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("li");

[].slice.apply(links).forEach(function(li,i){
  var step = i / (links.length - 1);
  var alpha = 1 - step * 0.5;
  li.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,155,0,' + alpha + ')';
});
```